# Is perl system return code the same as $?

Tags: perl, system, exit-code

Is the return value from Perl's system() call always the exact same value as $? will be immediately after the same call?

Are there any kernel/shell/system failure modes in which this will not be the case, such as system even failing to start a sub-shell?

(I'm **not** asking about the encoding of the bits, with the return code (in the high bits), signals, and core dump flag.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the return value from Perl's system() call always the exact same value as $? will be immediately after the same call?

Yes, they both come from Unix system call `wait()`.

According to [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html):

> The return value is the exit status of the program as returned by the `wait` call.

and [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables):

> `$?`
>   This is just the 16-bit status word returned by the traditional Unix `wait()` system call (or else is made up to look like it).

---

Note: according to the prototype of `wait(2)`, which is `pid_t wait(int *stat_loc)`, obviously, the return value of `system` is NOT the return value of `wait(2)`, which is a process id. It is the child process exit status returned by `wait(2)` through its first parameter, because a C function can only return one value, if it wants to return more than one value, it needs to wrap them in a structure and return a value of that structure type, or through parameters of pointer type.

Comment: It is amazing how many questions can be answered by reading the manual.

Comment: I read the manual, but the quoted section was not clear to me, as the return from the wait call is the process id, which system clearly does not return, and the phrasing could be interpreted multiple ways. Also, I wondered about failure conditions internal to the system() call as opposed to failures in the fork, the shell, or the program, which the manual does not address.

Comment: @user1663987 You misread that statement. You also should read the man page of `wait(2)`, this will clarify the meanings of that statement.

Comment: @user1663987: `wait` *returns* the process id, and it also stores the status in `$?`. The value that `wait` stores in `$?` is the same as the value *returned* by `system()`.

Comment: So if we allow the perl man page's "returned from wait" text to match the wait man page's "store[s] status information in the" first argument pointer text, then all is as it appears when running perl. But Keith, is your statement based on just the documentation (which I claim is not precisely written) or a more detailed familiarity of the operation? I ask since your statement implicitly says there can be no error condition returned from system() to indicate a system/fork/etc failure, aside from -1 which means "some other error, check !$". This is my experience, but I have always wondered.